# filter products by age in magento site

Tags: magento, filtering

We are developing a "toys for kids" magento site.

So we are planning for main categories = Boys & girls.

along with that we have to filter products as "0-2 years" , "2-4" years, "4-6years"..etc.

I guess it's similar like "shop by price[0-100] , [100-200] & shop by color".

you can see demo here, below gallery images  : http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/46006.html

please guide me to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps:

You can add Product Attribute from catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes.

1. Add your attribute dropdown type values

   0-2 years

   2-4 years

   4-6 years
2. Now save this attribute you need to set this attribute set.
3. Open product form admin panel and select attribute(age) value and save product.

Same way you can add price filter by create new attribute by select price type attribute.